# Modular multiplicative inverse function doesn't work for negative numbers

Tags: c++, modulo, inverse

I have the function below to calculate the  modular multiplicative inverse of a number n given the modulo number p.

```
int modInverse(int n, int p) {
    n %= p;
    for(int x = 1; x < p; x++) {
        if((n*x) % p == 1) return x;
    }
}
```

If n is positive, it wokrs fine, but if n is negative it gives always 0. 
How can I fix it?

Multiplicative inverse of x mod n: x^-1 mod n, is the number that must be multiplied by x to get 1 mod n 
e.g. 3^-1 mod 7 = 5, since 3 * 5 = 1 mod 7

Comment: Mod where first number is negative is implementation-defined until C++11 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Modular_inverse#C.2B.2B

Comment: @RobertHarvey I tried this as well and I'm still getting wrong results I think. If I try the number -17 with p=167 I should get back 59. The rosettacode function returns 1.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes on this, it's a good question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example code:

```
int modulo(int n, int p)
{
int r = n%p;
    if(((p > 0) && (r < 0)) || ((p < 0) && (r > 0)))
        r += p;
    return r;
}

int modInverse(int n, int p) {
    n = modulo(n, p);
    for(int x = 1; x < p; x++) {
        if(modulo(n*x, p) == 1) return x;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
int r;
    r = modInverse(-25, 7);
    return 0;
}
```

if you wanted a quotient and a remainder:

```
void divmod(int n, int p, int &q, int &r)
{
    q = n/p;
    r = n%p;
    if(((p > 0) && (r < 0)) || ((p < 0) && (r > 0))){
        q -= 1;
        r += p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I try the number -25 with 7 and I get a 5 instead of 3.

Comment: If I try r = modulo(-25,7); , it returns a 3 (using Visual Studio). (The quotient would be -4: -25 / 7 = -4, rem = +3).

Comment: Wait a minute. I'm not looking for the modulo function. I'm looking for the Multiplicative inverse of x mod n:
x^-1 mod n, is the number that must be multiplied by x to get 1 mod n
e.g. 3^-1 mod 7 = 5, since 3 * 5 = 1 mod 7

Comment: -25 modulo 7 == 3, so you're looking for the inverse of 3 modulo 7, which is 5, since (5*3) modulo 7 == 1.

Comment: What if I look for the inverse of -25 modulo 7. Does this even exist?

Comment: (-25 * 5) mod 7 = -125 mod 7 = 1, so 5 is the inverse of -25 mod 7, but 5 is also the inverse of (3 + n*7) mod 7 for any signed integer n. In your example, n = -4.

Comment: In the more typical case where both n and p are positive, n < p, and with no common factors (co-prime, which is always true if p is prime), then you can use the [extended Euclid algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures) .

Answer (score 1):

Besides unnecessary iterations, the method you are using has a `O(p)` complexity. You may want to use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm with a `O(log(p))` complexity. Anyway, answering to your question and the way you're doing it, I'd suggest you try this approach, which reduces the number of iterations: (Java)

```
int calculateInverse2(int a, int zp) {
    for (int i = (int) Math.ceil((zp-1)/a); i < zp; i++) {
        if (Math.floorMod(a*i,zp) == 1) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Related to negative values in modulo operation, depends upon the language. Try to implement a method which sums certain times `p` to establish the number within the integer ring.

Example:

`(-7)mod(2) => (-7+2)mod(2) => (-7+2+2)mod(2) => (-7+2+2+2)mod(6) => (-7+2+2+2+2)mod(6) => (1)mod(7)=1`

Easy to compute.